# STATUS_SINGLE_STEP in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, exception, x86

I am trying to add a `VEH handler` in my code, and in it, upon first **STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION**, I set the Trace bit to 1 by setting the `exc->ContextRecord->EFlags |= 0x100` so as to single step the violation.
 I see that the handler is getting called for **ACCESS_VIOLATION** but never getting called with `exc->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == STATUS_SINGLE_STEP` after stepping over the offending code.

I am suspecting that the debugger is removing the 0x100 from `the EFlags` when it runs its handler. If I run in a command prompt, I see that it is getting hit. Is there anyway I can make the debugger not alter the trace flag and allow my handler to get called with `ExceptionCode = STATUS_SINGLE_STEP`?

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to profile access to a particular piece of memory I allocated using `virtualalloc`. The first time VEH is called I enable RW access and set to `ContextRecord->EFlags |= 0x100` so as to trigger `STATUS_SINGLE_STEP` at which time I will enable protection to that piece of memory. This works in command prompt, but doesn't work in VS 2012

Comment: That's probably because VS 2012 being as it is a debugger, among other things, thinks that it should handle the exception in the usual way, as you suggest. It's hard to debug debugging code with a debugger ;)

Comment: I  wish it could be a bit smarter about it, and handle the setting up of EFlags in our handler appropriately.